# Terraform merge two resources for_each into one output, is it possible?

Tags: terraform

I would like to merge two output to file from two resources into one file.

I have this module to create user

```
module "iam_user_git_admin" {
  source                        = "../modules/terraform-aws-iam/modules/iam-user/"
  for_each                      = var.users
  name                          = each.value.name
  create_iam_user_login_profile = each.value.create_login_profile
  create_iam_access_key         = each.value.create_access_key

skip

}
```

then I'm creating login and password for AWS Codecommit

```
resource "aws_iam_service_specific_credential" "codecommit" {
  for_each     = toset([for u in module.iam_user_git_admin : u.iam_user_name])
  service_name = "codecommit.amazonaws.com"
  user_name    = each.value
}
```

Then I'm creating a file with credentials for each of the users. I know, it isn't secure. :)

```
resource "local_sensitive_file" "user_credentials" {
  for_each        = module.iam_user_git_admin
  file_permission = "0644"
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/template/user-credentials.tpl", {
    iam_user_name                             = coalesce(each.value.iam_user_name, "The data wasn't provided")

skip

  })
  filename = "./user_credentials-${each.value.iam_user_name}.txt"
}
```

and second file with credentials for codecommin

```
resource "local_sensitive_file" "user_credentials_codecommit" {
  for_each        = aws_iam_service_specific_credential.codecommit
  file_permission = "0644"
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/template/user-credentials-codecommit.tpl", {
    service_password               = coalesce(each.value.service_password, "The data wasn't provided")
  skip
  })
  filename = "./user_credentials-${each.value.service_user_name}.txt"
}
```

Prompt me, please, how can I merge it into one file.

Comment: Are there any outputs defined in the module?

Comment: @MarkoE - yes, all necessary output defined in module, except of codecommit related. I.e. needs to modernize this module, but it isn't a quick way :)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a set of resources using `for_each`, you can access an individual instance of that resource by [indexing the resource on the key you used to create it](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each#referring-to-instances). So you could do something like this:

```hcl
locals {
  users_map = { for u in var.users : u.name => u }
}

module "iam_user_git_admin" {
  for_each = local.users_map

  source                        = "../modules/terraform-aws-iam/modules/iam-user/"
  name                          = each.key
  create_iam_user_login_profile = each.value.create_login_profile
  create_iam_access_key         = each.value.create_access_key

  # skip

}

resource "aws_iam_service_specific_credential" "codecommit" {
  for_each = local.users_map

  service_name = "codecommit.amazonaws.com"
  user_name    = each.key
}

resource "local_sensitive_file" "user_credentials" {
  for_each = local.users_map

  file_permission = "0644"
  filename = "./user_credentials-${each.key}.txt"
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/template/user-credentials.tpl", {
    iam_user_name    = coalesce(module.iam_user_git_admin[each.key].iam_user_name, "The data wasn't provided")
    service_password = coalesce(aws_iam_service_specific_credential.codecommit[each.key].service_password, "The data wasn't provided")

    # skip

  })
}
```

Comment: This is correct if there is a proper output value defined in the module.

Comment: @Rostyslav Malenko did you resolve your problem?